# Is this a right code to disable MathJax right-clicking menu?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I use the code below

```
<script type="tet/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  showMathMenu: false
});
</script>
```

to disable right-clicking menu on my math website, however It seems not to work. Is it an outdated code or something?

Comment: This is for Mathjax version 2, are you using version 2 or 3?

Comment: @fast-reflexes I use version 3.2.0, thank you for pointing out the problem. Can you post the right way to disable context menu as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mathjax version 3, the information is here: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/menu.html

Use this configuration:

```
<script>
    MathJax = {
        ...
        options: {
            enableMenu: false
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

For version 2 the corresponding setting is documented here: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/hub.html#configure-hub

and involves the `showMathMenu` property listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to disable the right clicking, you can use the event listener for it and prevent the default behavior, something like:

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: I use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) on my website which uses its custom context menu. I have read the documentation, etc. However, I couldn't find the right solution. Anyways, thank you!